# Scala division result 0

Tags: scala, list, division

i am compiling this code and getting 0 on the division

```
println((MarkAnalysis.failAmount/Student.studentsId.length).toDouble + " " + MarkAnalysis.failAmount + " " + Student.studentsId.length)
```

I print it out to make sure that the division does not return zero, and

```
MarkAnalysis.failAmount = 14
MarkAnalysis.studentsId.length = 53
```

I dont understand why i get 0.0 on the result.

Comment: You're basically doing `(14/53).toDouble`. A division between integers is a integer. In this case 0. Then you convert it to Double.

Comment: ah, i see..
It was stupidity on my part..
Thank you.. @mfirry

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To hazzard a guess failAmount and studentId are both whole numbers (int or long), therefore the result is a whole number (i.e. int/int is int). Since 14<53 this would be 0 (14 doesn't fit even once in 53). Only after 0 is calculated it is converted to double.

**What You want** to do is a double division, and therefore need to convert to double before doing the division by adding `.toDouble` to at least one variable (better add to all in expression), e.g.:

```scala
MarkAnalysis.failAmount.toDouble/Student.studentsId.length.toDouble
```